# How to start launcher Minecraft in offline mode in a mac

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos, minecraft-launcher

I want to play on a local server with online mode false, but when I turn off wifi, instead of showing the play offline button, it shows the login screen. How do I get around this?

Comment: you dont have to be logged out

Comment: Did you save your username and password and make sure it remembers you?

Comment: I made sure it remembers me, but it still logs me out when I try to open the launcher without wifi.

Answer (score 1):

Open your launcher while the Wi-Fi is off. If it shows "Play Now", it means authentication succeeded and you didn't cut your Wi-Fi in time.

You can fix this by closing and reopening while **the computer is disconnected from the internet**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, when I go offline and opening the launcher, instead of showing "Play Offline" like a windows computer, it shows the launcher login screen that I can't use since the wifi is off.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to say that, if you want to play in a server with online mode set to false, your launcher does not need to show the button "play offline"

You can be logged in and connected to the internet and still be able to play on the server. What I am basically saying is you can join offline servers with a premium account, so you do not need turn off your Internet and play offline. I hope this solves your problem and helps you.